# Selenium Python I have an Xpath using Ancestor axis can i convert this to a CSS selector

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have an HTML page with a table of checkboxes.  Each checkbox has a name.
In col1 is the checkbox.  In col2 is the name.
I want to find the checkbox which has the name "Address"

I have managed to find it by using the following Xpath:

```
//table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_vars_usn"]/tbody//tr//td//div[contains(text(), "Address")]//ancestor::tr[1]//input[@type="checkbox"]
```

I locate the column which contains the text "Address"
I then use ancestor to go up 1 row to it's parent of the current node and locate the checkbox

I would like to use CSS, can this xpath be converted to use the CSS locator?
CSS is quicker than Xpath to locate elements on the web page.

The HTML is:

```
<table id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_vars_usn" class="GJPPK2LBJE" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
<thead aria-hidden="false">
<colgroup>
<tbody style="">
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD GJPPK2LBJD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED GJPPK2LBKD">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1204" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBKD">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1205" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBKD">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1206" style="outline-style:none;">
            <select tabindex="-1">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBKD">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD GJPPK2LBKD">
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBED">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1204" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1205" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDE GJPPK2LBOD">
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBED">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1204" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1205" style="outline-style:none;">DOB</div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBBD GJPPK2LBDD GJPPK2LBOD">
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
</tbody>
<tbody style="display: none;">
<tfoot style="" aria-hidden="false">
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the checkboxes is fixed you can use [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

```
input[type='checkbox']:nth-of-type(2)
```

This will find the second occurrence of `input[type='checkbox']`.
Or you can use [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

```
table#reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_vars_usn tr:nth-child(2) td input
```

This finds the second `tr` in the table, in that row a `td` with an `input`.

Comment: This is great, Thanks.

Comment: Can i use contains text to find the DOB instead of using nth element? In Xpath you can use the contains text keyword.  If i wanted to find Name, DOB i can use text.

Comment: Yes you can. Use the [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com) library. Here's an [article](http://seleniumtestingworld.blogspot.nl/2013/01/adding-sizzle-css-selector-library-and.html) about implementing it in Java. I don't know if there's python implementation of sizzle. Please accept my answer if you like it :)